# Converting JS output to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, valueconverter

Here is the code that I am currently using... (javascript injection)

---

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
  return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}
var imgList = [
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',   'img/1.jpg',
  'img/1.jpg',  'img/1.jpg'   // Note: No comma after last entry
];

function showImage() {
  var today = new Date();
  var weekno = today.getWeek();
  document.getElementById('WeeklyImage').src = imgList[weekno];
  document.getElementById('WeeklyImage').alt = imgList[weekno];
//  alert(weekno+'\t'+imgList[weekno]);
}
```

---

I was wondering if someone can tell me how I convert the image src to a php variable like $weeklyImage or something like that so I can do the following...

---

```
echo "<img src='" . $weeklyImage . "'>";
```

---

I need the output to be in PHP so that I can use the variable for other areas of the site that require PHP functions.

If not possible, any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: php has finished and gone home before the js starts

Comment: I agree with @Dagon.  This doesn't make any sense.  Php has served your content, javascript has done it's thing, and that's it.  There's no more PHP involved unless your talking about doing some sort of AJAX call (which you haven't mentioned in your question).

Comment: I'm stupid... I said it wrong.  I meant, that it ACTS like a js injection but want to convert the output to $weeklyImage instead of using the injection method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to directly pass values from JavaScript to PHP, because PHP runs on your server, then the result of your PHP script is sent to the client, and only then is JavaScript even run.

For your problem, there is absolutely no need to use JavaScript at all. You can get the current week with `date('W')` and similarly store the entire list of images in a simple array:

```
$images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'...];
echo '<img src="'.$images[date('W')].'">';
```

Comment: ok I got it.. shortened a bit to 

$weekly_image = "img/" . $weekNumber = date("W") . ".jpg";

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Just Cannot assign javascript variable value to a PHP variable just because

1. PHP is a Scripting Language
2. Php runs before javascript.
3. Thus the reverse is possible i.e. php variable can be assigned to a javascript variable.